# How to save mpdf generated file to a folder?

Tags: codeigniter, pdf, mpdf

I am having Problem in saving pdf generated by mPDF to a specific folder. Every thing is working fine with pdf generation, Only I am not able to save it to a local folder. Can any one help me out with that?

Comment: Is that folder already created? Do you have set the rights to writable? But most importantly is the var_dump path value for saving correct? It could also be a fact that you are using absolute path, which could be a problem (thank God for that) from security reasons. So, try to use relative paths if possible. thats my advice. Anyway your question lacks a lot of info, so it could be deleted. try to add some more information to prevent taht from happening. Thanks.

Comment: Well you are right. The only problem is the the mpdf library sets the pdf in outputas $mpdf->output(); but I want to save this pdf in my folder. So, that i can use it in email later. Actually, I am generating invoice and this invoice should be sent to user email

Comment: Then just save it using CI's upload library.

Comment: I have done this way: $this->mpdf->Output(realpath(APPPATH.'../file/invoice/')."arif.pdf",'F'); but the file is being saved in file directory instead of invoice folder

Answer (score 5):

Short answer is to put the full path where you plan to save the file. Like so...

```
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output('/etc/home/JohnWayne/example/pdf/','F');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use write file helper for this

```
$this->load->helper('file');
write_file('my_pdf_file.pdf',$generated_pdf);
```

[File Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/file_helper.html)

For this follow these simple steps. Follow BASEPATH instead of APPPATH

```
$path   =   BASEPATH . 'file/invoice';

if(is_dir($path)){
    $this->mpdf->Output(realpath($path).'arif.pdf','F'); 
}else{
    echo 'error';
}
```

### EDITS :

Here is an alternative solution which you might like
Go to application/config/constants.php and add constant there

```
define('FILE_PATH' , $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."my_project/file/");
```

Then use it like this.

```
$this->mpdf->Output(FILE_PATH ."invoice/arif.pdf",'F');
```

Comment: Will this work ?
    
    write_file(base_url().'file/my/mypdf.pdf',$this->mpdf->output());

Comment: I have done this way: $this->mpdf->Output(realpath(APPPATH.'../file/invoice/')."arif.pdf",'F');

Comment: But the file is being saved in file directory not the invoice directory.Can you tell me why this is happening ?

Comment: can you check if directory with invoice exists. Than write the file in it.

Comment: Thank you. I have also alternate that works now. See my answer bellow

Comment: @MohammadArif where is your answer?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. This is very simple. As for as mPDF library is concerned, it does not parse the base_url(). Instead we have to work with $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; In my case i have done as; Open the config.php in Application/config folder and insert the following;

```
$config['file_path']=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."my_project/file/";
```

Now it is a peace of cake to call the config; Here is I have done in the controller;

```
$this->mpdf->Output($this->config->item('file_path')."invoice/arif.pdf",'F');
```

The Problem is solved. Do let me know if there is any technical or logical issue with my code.

Answer (score 1):

make a folder in your root directry

```
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output(FCPATH.'PDF/Broker.pdf','F');
echo $Ledger_Group_Report = base_url().'PDF/Broker.pdf';
```